# call different html files which contain graphs and superpose them in order to be able to compare them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am in a big trouble, please i need help !
I am about to compare different data using Fusion Chart, i was able to make a chart for every object in my checkbox, my problem is, how to call these html files and superpose them whilst clicking on more than one checkbox in order to compare them ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Interface</title>


</head>

<body>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="transfert.php" target="_blank">
<p>Date de Debut : 
<input type="date" name="date1" id="champ_date1" size="12" maxlength="20" /></p>

<p>Date de Fin : 
<input type="date" name="date2" id="champ_date1" size="12" maxlength="20" /> </p>

<p> choisir KPI </p>
 
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="TotalVoiceTrafficBH1" > TotalVoiceTrafficBH1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="TotalVoiceTrafficBH2" > TotalVoiceTrafficBH2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="CSSRBH1" > CSSRBH1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="CSSRBH2" > CSSRBH2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="TCHBlockingBH1" >TCHBlockingBH1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="TCHBlockingBH2" > TCHBlockingBH2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="SDCHHBlockingBH1" >SDCHHBlockingBH1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="SDCCHBlockingBH2" >SDCCHBlockingBH2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="SDCCHDropBH1" > SDCCHDropBH1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="SDCCHDropBH2" > SDCCHDropBH2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="TCHDropBH1" > TCHDropBH1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="TCHDropBH2" > TCHDropBH2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="HOSRBH1" > HOSRBH1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="HOSRBH2" > HOSRBH2<br>

<p><input type="submit" value="Afficher" size="15"/>
</p>
</form>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function checkValue() {
  var checkedValue = null;
  var inputElements = document.getElementsByName('check_list[]');
  for (var i = 0; inputElements[i]; ++i) {
    if (inputElements[i].checked) {
      checkedValue = inputElements[i].value;
      break;
    }
    return checkedValue;
  }
}
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
if (checkValue()== 'SDCHHBlockingBH1')
{
iframe.src = 'http://localhost/xampp/www/interactive_php_mysql_charts/chart_trans7.html';
  iframe.width='700';
  iframe.height='500';
  iframe.align='right';
        break;
}

else if (checkValue()== 'SDCHHBlockingBH2')
{
iframe.src = 'http://localhost/xampp/www/interactive_php_mysql_charts/chart_trans8.html';
  iframe.width='700';
  iframe.height='500';
  iframe.align='right';
        break;
}
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here i used iframe in order to overlay one over another, but it doesnt work, any suggestions please, even with no iframes ?

Comment: This is far too broadly scoped question. Also approach of trying to overlay html charts on top of each other doesn't make much sense either. Making one chart with multiple sets of data would seem more practical. You really need to scale this down into smaller sub issues and solve each individually. Nobody is going to give you a solution or write you a tutorial for this whole scope. See [ask]

Comment: I want to make one chart with muliple sets of data, but my problem is that these data are retrieving from an sql data base, they are not manual data as i see into different exampleswith pChart, FusionChart or whatever. added to this the user is free to choose data to retrieve via a checkbox. Any idea ?

Comment: Sure lots of ideas. Why would data from database be any different than other data?

Comment: Because manual data, you can write them directly like this for example:  $DataSet->AddPoint(array(1,4,3,4,3,3,2,1,0,7,4,3,2,3,3,5,1,0,7),"Serie1");  
$DataSet->AddPoint(array(1,4,2,6,2,3,0,1,5,1,2,4,5,2,1,0,6,4,2),"Serie2");

Comment: But what will i set in AddPoint with data retrieved from an sql data base ? and only data already choosed bu the user ?

Comment: And why can't that be written using database data?Unfortunately it sounds like your skills regarding all aspects of this are not strong enough. You need to start small and get one graph working with json data from server before you tackle superimposing anything. Can't eat an elephant all in one bite

Comment: i was able to get one graph working with json data from server with an html file, this is why i need to call these html file (every file contain one graph) and superpose them.

Comment: Well even that concept makes no sense to me. Think about one chart with multiple sets of json data. And is that chart working from database? Get that working

Comment: yes, that chart is working from data base. I was working on setting multiple data with one chart, but it doesnt work with me, this is why i thought like this. I will try more and more.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be...

1. create a container div with CSS "position: relative;"
2. create 3 chart container divs with CSS

   ```
   position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0; 
   opacity: .3;
   ```

You may need to do some pre-processing on your HTML call to populate the divs with the charts (strip out head and body, so you just have a div with the chart content), or else extract the chart HTML into templates that you can call. I'm not sure what the limitations are here.

Another approach might be to use a server plugin that creates an image of the chart div or chart page, then call the image from your app. I may be mistaken but I think there is a GIMP server plugin that can do this.